# How to use foobar2000 commandline interface to delete the currently playing file?

Tags: command-line, foobar2000

According to [this article](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Commandline_Guide) , the command needed to delete the currently playing file is

`foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"Delete file(s)"`

but for some reason that doesn't work.

Note that other similar commands DO work, such as

`foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"Open containing folder"`

this properly opens the currently running file.

I thought this may be due to the fact that the string `Delete file(s)` has those problematic parentheses, so I tried the following variations:

`foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"Delete file(s)"
foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"Delete file"
foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"Delete"
foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"delete"
foobar2000.exe /playing_command:"del"`

none of those which worked.

In the same breath, I can't get the following to work either:

`foobar2000.exe "/playing_command:Remove from playback queue"`

Comment: 1/ `^` is the escape character for parentheses, 2/ `foobar2000.exe "/playing_command:Remove from playback queue"` you have the quotes n the wrong place.